# pandas df loop through column resulting in KeyError 1

Tags: python, pandas

I have an if loop that's throwing a keyerror 1 when i try to reference a location in a dataframe, which has been imported with pandas. I only receive this error on windows, the loop runs in os - this command also works outside of a loop. what am I do wrong?
I am running though a column and if and of the string values = a specific string, I want it to tell me.I also tried .loc[i] and that didnt work in the loop either

```
    i=0
    for R in df:
        i=i+1
        if df['Data status'][i] == 'In progress':
            print ('temp')
        else:
            print ('not')
```

Comment: IIUC, Try this ... df['print_value'] = ['temp' if val == 'In progress' else 'not' for val in df['Data status']]. This will create a new column in your dataframe with appropriate 'temp and 'not' values.

Comment: Can you provide a minimal working example? And the error output? It appears that since `i` is incremented before looking at `df['Data status'][i]`, on the last loop you will be querying an index that doesn't exist. Confused why it would work on OSX and not Windows though.

Comment: A few suggestions to simplify the code: `i=i+1` can be replaced with `i+=1`. Also, since you don't appear to use the variable `R`, you may consider using `for i in range(len(df)):` instead, or if you do want to use `R` later, even better is `for i, R in enumerate(df):`

Comment: @cadams this is just a simplified loop, my other loop i have i = -1 at the beginning and it still generates the same error, before I did have it run through too many loops, and it would still output until it ran into the last loop, then throw an error.
Also thanks for the tip on the i+=1

Comment: @Anshul Good thought, but i don't this that is going to work for the bigger picture of my code unfortunately =[  I don't want to add more to the spreadsheet, essentially i am flagging specific data statuses then doing further analysis on the rows, this loop is just my troubleshooting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so generally the `for` loop is redundant there. You can leverage vectorized operations here:

In case if you want to create new column with the mentioned values:

```py
import numpy as np
df['new_column']=np.where(df['Data status'].eq("In progress"), "temp", "not")
```

In case if you want some processing to be done on the side, depending on the value, which would justify the `for` loop - just do:

```py
import numpy as np
arr=np.where(df['Data status'].eq("In progress"), "temp", "not")

for el in arr:
    print(el)
    if(el=="temp"):
        Do_something()
    else:
        Do_something_else()
```

In case I totally misread your intentions, and you just want to make your code work, for some higher purpose, just do (it's also way more pythonish approach):

```py
# i is row index, and R is the single row
for i,R in df.iterrows():
    if R['Data status'] == 'In progress':
        print ('temp')
    else:
        print ('not')
```

Comment: Thanks! the last subsection of code is exactly what I needed. Still confused why my original code runs on my mac but not my pc all else being the same.... either way, this is perfect, thanks!,

Answer (score 0):

Your code has the following flaws:

1. Your loop `for R in df:` iterates over **column names**.
   So if your DataFrame has e.g. 3 columns, you attempt to process just 3 rows.
2. `df['Data status']` is a *Series* - a column with this name.
   It has **index**, just the same as the whole DataFrame.
   By default it consists of consecutive numbers starting from *0*,
   but I don't know whether the index in your DataFrame is just like
   this. It can also contain other values, maybe dates, maybe strings,
   you failed to provide any data on this detail.
3. Apparently your code failed in the first turn of the loop,
   when *i* was *1* (after increment from *0*), when `df['Data status'][i]`
   attempted to refer to element of *Data status* column with
   index *1*. I assume that your DataFrame does not contain
   index == *1*, hence *KeyError* exception was raised.

To process your DataFrame, row by row, try the following code:

```
for ind, row in df.iterrows():
    if row['Data status'] == 'In progress':
        print(ind, 'temp')
    else:
        print(ind, 'not')
```

In the code above:

- *ind* is the index of the curent row,
- *row* is the current row itself.